# Is there a maximum for Mixer ingredients in Wonderful 101?

Tags: the-wonderful-101

In the mixer service you can use in the Wonderful 101, there are three ingredients (so far, just completed mission 001C). If there a maximum of these ingredients? The maximum that can be used in a mix are 30, and I haven't collected as much yet. But if I cannot exceed the 30 limit, I will use some of them right now instead of letting them going to waste.

[image: Mixer image]

Comment: Incidentally, if you press the Home button and navigate to an image-upload form, you can upload a screenshot directly from the Wii U itself without having to deal with this take-a-picture-of-the-TV nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold a max of **99** of each of the three ingredients. So once you're approaching 90, you should mix something.